# Is it possible to fetch the blockchain state at an specific block?

Tags: web3.js

I'm trying to build a report, and for that, I need to fetch the state of the blockchains at different points in time (at different heights/slots). I would expect `@solana/web3.js` to support doing things like:

```
conn.getBalance(pubKey, {block: 170.000})
conn.getInflationReward([publicKey], {block: 170.000})
```

...but it doesn't seem to support that, as other blockchains do.

Any ideas on how I could fetch blockchain state from an arbitrary block height?

Comment: This isn't possible at the moment through RPC. You have to build the state of the blockchain using a validator snapshot or by regularly storing chain data in a separate database

Comment: What "state of the blockchain" are you trying to find? If you could share your end goal here and what info you are trying to actually get to, maybe we can help you find it some other way.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was trying to find the daily staked value and rewards. I ended up using the `getInflationRewards` method at different epochs, which returns. `postBalance` and `rewards`, to build the final report I need.